# Atomic swaps in Ethereum

Tags: solidity, transactions

Nowadays there is a lot of discussion about Bitcoin hashed time locks which would unleash some new applications like atomic swaps. In Bitcoin every new logic must be implemented at client-code level while in Ethereum some flexibility is allowed by contract code. Can atomic swaps be implemented with user code in Ethereum?

Comment: Yes, it should be possible see this example [Ethereum Cross Chain Atomic Swaps](https://medium.com/@DontPanicBurns/ethereum-cross-chain-atomic-swaps-5a91adca4f43). One advantage of ethereum is you can reuse the contract.

Comment: @Ismael your comment is good enough to be answer. Do you want to migrate it?

Comment: @Atav32 Sorry, I'm kind of busy right now, if you want to write an answer please feel free to do so.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, through the use of Ethereum Cross Chain Atomic Swaps. Details can be found here:

https://medium.com/@DontPanicBurns/ethereum-cross-chain-atomic-swaps-5a91adca4f43

Comment: Link only answer are not recommended because if the page is deleted or the server is down then the answer becomes invalid. It is better to include the main points in the answer itself and use the link to expand it.

Comment: why not you give the answer?